# Is literal translation of book titles always appropriate?

Tags: translation

I'm translating a comic book ["The Ogre Gods"](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/ComicBook/TheOgreGods) (Les Ogres-Dieux). It is written by а French author Hubert Boulard.

So, I think that for non-English readers it is appropriate to translate this title as "The Family Tree of Ogres" or "The Ogre ('s) Family Tree". Because this story tells us about some characters/members from the ogre dynasty. At least the first tome. (The second tome is focused on some human-nobles in the ogre society).

I consider that the title "Ogre Gods" tells nothing to comic readers of my country. Because these giants are not gods. They are just big guys who rule the kingdome (of course in their own big castle on the mountain) where humans live. There was the only one ogre who believed that he was God-King. And it's all.

My question is. Should I use literal translation for this comic book or could I translate it in more comprehensible way for readers, so they immediately understand what is this story about?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question. It isn't about learning English.  It's a question for [writing.se] because the titleling of books is not something that an English teacher has any skills in, but  a writer might. The same question could apply  to a Russian to French translation question, indicating that this has nothing to do with English learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How something should be translated usually depends on the purpose of the translation.

If this is a comic book for children that you are hoping to sell in a different country, then the goal should be to make it appealing to children (and their parents). It is important that they immediately understand the meaning so they can enjoy it. Even the Harry Potter books were "translated" from British English to American English so that America audiences would understand and enjoy them more.

If the goal is to make the book available for academic research, then a more literal translation is called for. The professors and students can be expected to spend more time figuring out what is being said, without losing as much nuance of the original language.

Comment: the purpose of the translation is just translation for a fanbase (comic readers and comic translators) who like that author and his works. I'm not going to sell this translation and it is not an academic research, One of the readers wrote to me and stated that my translation of the title is not correct. He or she thinks that only literal translation is appropriate. So I asked this question here.

Comment: I understood your explanation. Thank you, it helps a lot!

Comment: There is absolutely no rule that titles of works have to be translated literally. For example, _Notre-Dame de Paris_ is known as _The Hunchback of Notre-Dame_ in English.